# Symfony 2.8 Shared Hosting Deployment App.php Blank Page

Tags: php, symfony, ftp, composer-php, shared-hosting

I've created a Symfony 2.8 web application and it is working well (both app.php and app_dev.php). As I need to deploy in a shared hosting (no access to ssh, only via ftp), i copied the entire folder including the vendors and uploaded it via ftp. Now I can access the website fully on app_dev.php.

The problem is that when I try to access the site in app.php, it displays a blank page.

I have already checked/done the following things:

1. No app/cache/prod folder was created
2. No prod logs was created
3. While debugging using app.php, i realized that an echo before :

   ```
   echo "Hello";
   $loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
   include_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
   ```

and

```
    $loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
    echo "Hello";
    include_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
```

works. BOTH PRINT HELLO in the browser.

BUT IF put echo below include bootstrap.php.cache, i GET THE WHITE PAGE.

```
    $loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
    include_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
    echo "Hello"; // DOEST PRINT HELLO IN BROWSER
```

4. If I remove the bootstrap.include, the page displays.
5. I have already done the following commands to generate the bootstrap file

   ```
   1. composer install
   2. composer update
   ```

Can someone tells me what is the real problem in fact? And of course, its solution.

Comment: pls show us error log, if log is generated

Comment: the problem is that it stops at the line include_once(boostrap.cache.php), no logs are generated